# CSS background-image transition makes video tag buffer

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, html5-video, css-transitions

I have a video tag that I want to play continuously while a user can simultaneously do stuff on the site. However I have found that if the background transitions between background images that the video starts buffering. I have a runnable example in the snippet below.

**Note:** The buffering does not seem to occur if the snippet is run normally, but does occur if you put the snippet in 'full page'.

```js
function changeBackground() {
  const randomColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  const element = document.getElementById('background');
  const currentOpacity = element.style.opacity;
  const currentBackground = element.style.backgroundImage;
  
  switch (currentBackground) {
    case 'url("https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/stackoverflow-com-logo-png-transparent.png")': {
      element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Large/428/5_r/6000195494285_R.jpg")';
      break;
    }
    case 'url("https://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Large/428/5_r/6000195494285_R.jpg")': {
      element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/stackoverflow-com-logo-png-transparent.png")';
      break;
    }
    default: {
      break;
    }
  }
}
 
 const element = document.getElementById('background');
 element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/stackoverflow-com-logo-png-transparent.png")'
```

```css
#background {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
  
  background-size: contain;
  
  transition: background-image 3s ease-in-out;
}

#button {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

#video {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id='root' style='width: 100%; height: 500px'>
    <div id='background'></div>
    <div id='button' onClick="changeBackground()">Click me to change the background!</div>
    <video
      id='video'
      autoplay
      muted
      loop
      controls
      src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_video-cute.mp4"/>
</div>
```

What could be the cause and is there a way to prevent the video from buffering while still having a background image transition?

Edit: May be important to add that I'm on Chrome on MacOS.

Edit 2: From the responses I have gathered not everyone can reproduce the problem, so I went to an old-timey windows PC and tried it there. Found out that the background-transition was being really slow and laggy but the video kept playing without problem. It also works on safari on MacOS so this appears to be a **Chrome MacOS-only** problem.

Comment: I tried several times (Chrome on Win10) and it does not behave like this all the time. Somtimes it doesn't show buffering, sometimes only on the first transition.

Comment: It appears to not happen on Windows when I tested and according to your and zer00nes responses but it does happen on multiple Macs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit I'm not entirely sure of what happens here... Given it's not a 100% repro case, it's also hard to be sure any workaround actually works...

But here are some comments and ideas.

---

It seems this happens only with *.mp4* files. I could reproduce with other *.mp4* videos but never with any *.webm* file.
So one thing you may want to try is to reencode your video in webm, it could be that Chrome's mp4 decoder has some issues.

---

It seems that CSS *animations* do not cause this issue. So you could rewrite your transition code into a CSS animation, with the major problem that you won't be able to stop it in the middle (but it seems background-transitions are bad at this anyway).

```js
function changeBackground() {
  const element = document.getElementById('background');
  if(element.classList.contains('apple')) {
    element.classList.remove('apple');
    element.classList.add('so');
  }
  else {
    element.classList.add('apple');
    element.classList.remove('so');
  }

}
```

```css
#background {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
  
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/stackoverflow-com-logo-png-transparent.png");
}
#background.apple {
  animation: apple-to-SO 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}
#background.so {
  animation: SO-to-apple 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}
@keyframes apple-to-SO {
  from {
    background-image: url("https://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Large/428/5_r/6000195494285_R.jpg")
  }
  to {
    background-image: url("https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/stackoverflow-com-logo-png-transparent.png");
  }
}
@keyframes SO-to-apple {
  from {
    background-image: url("https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/stackoverflow-com-logo-png-transparent.png");
  }
  to {
    background-image: url("https://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Large/428/5_r/6000195494285_R.jpg")
  }
}

#button {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

#video {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id='root' style='width: 100%; height: 500px'>
    <div id='background'></div>
    <div id='button' onClick="changeBackground()">Click me to change the background!</div>
    <video
      id='video'
      autoplay
      muted
      loop
      controls
      src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_video-cute.mp4"/>
</div>
```

Now if you prefer js control, it seems that Web-Animations aren't affected either.

```js
let current = 1;
const urls = [
  "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/stackoverflow-com-logo-png-transparent.png",
  "https://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Large/428/5_r/6000195494285_R.jpg"
];
function changeBackground() {
  const element = document.getElementById('background');
  element.animate({
      backgroundImage: ['url(' + urls[current] + ')', 'url(' + urls[+(!current)] + ')']
      }
    , {
      duration: 3000,
      iterations: 1,
      fill: 'both'
    }
  );
  current  = (current + 1) % 2;
}
```

```css
#background {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
  
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/stackoverflow-com-logo-png-transparent.png);
}


#button {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

#video {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id='root' style='width: 100%; height: 500px'>
    <div id='background'></div>
    <div id='button' onClick="changeBackground()">Click me to change the background!</div>
    <video
      id='video'
      autoplay
      muted
      loop
      controls
      src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_video-cute.mp4"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and good catch that it doesn't seem to buffer with a .webm file. As for .mp4's unfortunately snippet #1 still seems to have the issue for me (albeit it looks better but maybe im imagining things). #2 doesn't animate on click and gives the error '"Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute `animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported.`. Any idea on how to fix that one?

Comment: Oups, my bad I forgot I had Experimental Features on and that this syntax is still not supported in stable...

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable / disable hardware-acceleration on Chrome.

Comment: This does seem to work but I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't require my users to change chrome settings. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I know that you expect a solution, but your code seems fine for me. After reading a little I saw the bufering is a common problem of Chrome under OS. I hope to solve the problem with the help of this guy's.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem so it might be an issue with your ISP and latency (I don't have that problem at 145 Mbps). Looking at your code it isn't very efficient with that switch. The demo below uses an array (added another image as well). BTW add flex to elements that contain children elements otherwise it's pointless.

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = changeBackground;
let i = 0;

function changeBackground(e) {
  const images = ["https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/stackoverflow-com-logo-png-transparent.png", "https://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Large/428/5_r/6000195494285_R.jpg", "https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/circuit-board-seamless-pattern-vector-background-microchip-technology-vector-id1018272944"];
  const background = document.getElementById('background');

  i++;
  if (i >= images.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
  background.style.backgroundImage = `url(${images[i]})`;
  return false;
}
```

```css
#background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/stackoverflow-com-logo-png-transparent.png);
  transition: background-image 3s ease-in-out;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

#video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id='root' style='width: 100%; height: 500px'>
  <div id='background'></div>
  <div id='button'>Click me to change the background!</div>
  <video id='video' autoplay muted loop controls src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_video-cute.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately I see the same buffering of the video with your improved code. I think it may have something to do with processing power then?

Answer (score 0):

This question is interesting.

I think the buffer may be due to

1. This line Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
2. also about the video resolution and to what extent it has been resized
3. also may be due to some unnecessary codes if any.